# Automatically get missing package dependencies

Tags: ros, catkin, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been looking for this for some time now. There is a lot of question about dependencies but I didn't really find what I needed.
I am working on a raspberry pi where there is no prebuilt packages.
I installed the minimal version of ROS and some packages are missing.
Now I want to compile my own package that needs those missing packages.
What would be the command to automatically fetch the sources of all those missing packages and compile eveything in the right order?
I tried

```
catkin-make --rosdep-install
```

but it doesn't seem to work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212772/automatically-get-missing-package-dependencies/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-02**:
I think this can be done with the rosinstall generator, but I don't remember the specific options that you'd need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the packages you are missing using `rosinstall_generator`.

First you'll want to source the setup file for any packages you already have:

```
$ source /path/to/setup.bash
```

This will put the packages you already have on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (RPP). Then you can ask `rosinstall_generator` to generate a rosinstall file which contains all the packages you need:

```
$ rosinstall_generator <pkg1> <pkg2> ... <pkgn> --rosdistro indigo --deps --deps-only --tar --exclude RPP > my.rosisntall
```

You can replace the `<pkg1> <pkg2> ... <pkgn>` with a white space separated list of the packages you have for which you want to install the dependencies. The `--rosdistro` option tells it what ROS distribution to pull these packages from, the `--deps` option tells it to get the dependencies of the packages you specified, the `--deps-only` tells it to avoid including the packages you specified (I assume you already have those), and the `--tar` option tells it to get tarballs instead of git/hg repositories if possible (downloads it faster). Finally the `--exclude RPP` option tells it to avoid adding packages which it can find on your local RPP. It puts all of this out to stdout, so we can pipe that into a rosinstall file with `> my.rosinstall`, the name of which doesn't really matter.

After you run this you can look at the result in the file or run it without the redirection and see that it makes sense. It shouldn't contain packages you already have built nor the packages you are going to build, but a list of packages in between those.

Once you have the rosinstall file as you like you can fetch the packages in it with `wstool`:

```
$ wstool init ~/extra_catkin_ws/src my.rosinstall -j8
```

If you later need to generate additional rosinstall files, they can be merged into the workspace like this:

```
$ wstool merge -t ~/extra_catkin_ws/src other.rosinstall
$ wstool up -t ~/extra_catkin_ws/src -j8
```

Then you can follow the general pattern that is shown in the source install instructions for ROS, doing rosdep and then one of the catkin commands:

```
$ cd ~/extra_catkin_ws
$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
$ catkin_make_isolated
```

Hope that helps,

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-07-03**:
doing this for image_transport for example returns : No packages/stacks left after applying the exclusions
even though the dependency plugin_lib is missing. When I don't exclude RPP I get a lot of packages like ros_core but also plugin_lib

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-03**:
Then that means you have all of the ROS dependencies you need to build image_transport.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-07-07**:
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pluginlib" with
any of the following names:

```
pluginlibConfig.cmake
pluginlib-config.cmake
```

What should I consider while trying to find out what is wrong here with rosinstall_generator?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-07-07**:
So in my case pluginlib is missing but running
rosinstall_generator pluginlib --deps --exclude RPP > my.rosinstall I get:
Using ROS_DISTRO: indigo
No packages/stacks left after applying the exclusions